# Not seeing admin panel properly after magento 2 installed

Tags: magento2, admin

After installing magento 2 i am seeing admin panel is not getting loaded properly. Also the website is showing error.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a known issue in magento 2 manual installation.Load static content through your terminal .The command to run is 
 `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` 
If you are still having the issue then replace this line of code in your setup app/etc/di.xml
 `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink`
to 
 `Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy`
Hope this solves your problem.